# How can I force Filepicker.io to send Cache-Control headers to Amazon S3?

Tags: python, django, caching, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

I'm using Filepicker.io and Django with the [official library](https://github.com/Filepicker/django-filepicker) and I've noticed two things:

- The URLs it provides to Django are direct to my S3 bucket, not the Filepicker URLs.
- It doesn't set any caching on the files it sends whatsoever.

Since I'm using this mainly for images which will be reloaded kinda often, I'm wondering how I can make Filepicker set Cache-Control headers.

Alternatively, is it possible to force Amazon S3 to set Cache-Control headers on every single object that goes into a bucket automatically?

Comment: Perhaps you could use CloudFront, which is Amazons Content Delivery Network. You can set cache headers and Cloud Front easily links into S3, this would be the preferred solution as S3 isn't really designed for speedy content delivery.

Comment: @krak3n Good idea! I actually just switched it to a URL field and used Filepicker's cache=true query string parameter but I think I might switch to Cloudflare for my CDN and tell it to force caching.

Comment: @user478250 even better, do both so that CloudFront caches and serves Ink's public cache headers.